# Configure php-cgi on Windows using Yeoman

Tags: php, windows, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

Can anyone help me configure php-cgi in Windows 7? I'm trying to do what is described in this [tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/bal2_a) and I'm not getting through to Windows. I've researched various things on the internet and tried a few, but was not successful. Would anyone help me how can I do this to make it work?

Comment: Would you explain what you are specifically having problems with? This question may not be an ideal fit for Stack Overflow for two reasons: it is rather broad, and it depends entirely on a third-party link that could become unavailable or be deleted (if that happens, the question is no longer useful for future readers). Would you edit to explain what errors you are seeing, for example?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need PHP on the commandline, PHP is easy enough to install. It's just a case of unzipping the .zip file, duplicating php.ini-development as php.ini, then you should be good to go, unless you need to add any extensions, or change any settings (for this tutorial, you shouldn't need to do anything more than this).

If you want to get it running quickly with IIS on Windows, the quickest and easiest way I've found is to use [PHP Manager](http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/).  It'll set up a fast CGI handler for PHP for you just by navigating to the PHP executable and it's all easily configurable via an icon in IIS Manager.

Comment: I understand you tkns, but [here](https://github.com/fgnass/gateway)  says  "To make this work you need the php-cgi binaray in your PATH."
I don't know how I can do that :(
I work with php, but I've never used with yeoman u_u

Comment: Path refers to the computers list of paths where it looks for things such as executables: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable) You can set this variable via the "System Properties" dialog: Press your Windows key and Pause key, then click "Advanced settings" on the left-hand side (assuming you're using Windows 7).

Comment: In Linux I just did "sudo apt-get install php5-cgi" and it works for me, but Windows I don't know -.-'

Comment: Ensure you restart any cmd windows you have open after changing your path, otherwise it will not take effect.  All I can suggest at this point is following the documentation on PHP.net: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php is the best place to start.